# Exploring the convergence properties of a cost function involving orthogonal projection of one-hot vectors

Tags: optimization, matrix-calculus, machine-learning, gradient-descent, exponential-sum

$\newcommand{bm}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}$Given the semi-orthogonal fat matrix ${\bm B} \in\mathbb R^{c \times d}$ (i.e., $c\leq d$, $\bm {BB}^\top=\bm I$), the matrix $\bm X \in {\Bbb R}^{m \times n}$, $c$ one-hot vectors $\mathbf y_1, \mathbf y_2, \dots, \mathbf y_c \in \mathbb R^c$, let the cost function $J : {\Bbb R}^{m \times d} \to {\Bbb R}$ be defined by

$$J ({\bm W}) := -\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{1 + \frac1{c-1} \sum\limits_{1\leq j\leq c \wedge \bm y_j\neq \bm y_i} \exp \left((\bm y_j-\bm y_i)^\top \bm B\bm W^\top\bm x_i \right)}$$

Let $\bm X = \begin{bmatrix} \bm x_1 & \bm x_2 & \dots & \bm x_n \end{bmatrix}$; $n>c$. I have worked out the gradient $\nabla_{\bm W}J$ as:

$$\nabla_{\bm W}J=\frac1{n(c-1)}\bm X\left[\bm M-\mathrm {diag}(\bm M\bm e)\bm Y^\top\right]\bm B$$

where $\bm e = 1^{c\times 1}$. $\bm Y\in (0, 1)^{c\times n}$ is a fixed "one-hot" column vector matrix where $\bm y_i$ corresponds to $\bm x_i$, and $\bm M\in\mathbb R_+^{n\times c}$ is a matrix of scaled exponential elements such that
$$M_{ij} = J_i^2\exp\left((\bm y_j-\bm y_i)^\top \bm B\bm W^\top\bm x_i\right)$$

where $J_i$ is the $i$th summation term in $J$.

I am trying to understand the convergence properties of $J$. Prima facie looking at $J$, it appears that $J$ is minimized when $\Vert\bm W\Vert\to\infty$ and $(\bm y_j-\bm y_i)^\top \bm B\bm W^\top\bm x_i<0 ,\forall ij$. However, when I look at the gradient, we have at convergence:
$$\bm X\left[\bm M-\mathrm {diag}(\bm M\bm e)\bm Y^\top\right]\bm B=\bm 0$$

Although I understand that
$$(\Vert\bm W\Vert\to\infty;(\bm y_j-\bm y_i)^\top \bm B\bm W^\top\bm x_i<0,\forall ij)\implies\nabla_{\bm w}J\to\bm 0\implies\bm M\to\bm Y^\top\implies J\to-1$$
but from looking at the equation, it would appear that there might be local minima in the function since, in general, $\bm X\bm A\bm B=\bm 0$ does not require that $\bm A=\bm 0$.

If so, given that $\bm X$ and $\bm B$ are fixed, can we somehow find the conditions on $\bm M$ that result in convergence?

---

**Update:**

Noting that $\bm {BB}^\top=\bf I$, simplifies the convergence $\nabla_{\bm W}J=\bm 0$ to:

$$\bm X\bm M=\bm X\mathrm {diag}(\bm M\bm e)\bm Y^\top$$
$$\implies\bm M^\top\bm X^\top=\bm Y\mathrm {diag}(\bm M\bm e)\bm X^\top$$

This tells me that $\bm M^\top$ is equivalent to a transformation that projects $\bm X^\top$ onto $\bm Y$ scaled by $\mathrm {diag}(\bm M\bm e)$. If we let $\Vert\bm W\Vert\to\infty$ during minimization, then $\bm M\to\bm Y^\top\implies\mathrm {diag}(\bm M\bm e)\to \bm I^n$. I guess then my question is equivalent to the following:

"Does there exist a diagonal matrix with distinct elements, i.e., $\mathrm{diag}(\bm M\bm e)\neq  k\bm I^n$ for some finite $\Vert\bm W\Vert$ such that the above expression holds?"

---

**Calculation of $\nabla_{\bm W}J$**

There seems to be some confusion in comments regarding the expression I am getting for the gradients. Here is what I am doing:

$$\nabla_{\bm W}J=\bm X(\nabla_{\bm W^\top\bm X}J)^\top$$

where $\nabla_{\bm W^\top\bm X}J=\begin{bmatrix}\nabla_{\bm W^\top\bm x_1}J & \nabla_{\bm W^\top\bm x_2}J & \dots & \nabla_{\bm W^\top\bm x_n}J \end{bmatrix}$. Now, $\nabla_{\bm W^\top\bm x_i}J$ can be calculated as:
$$\nabla_{\bm W^\top\bm x_i}J=\frac{J_i^2}{n(c-1)}\bm B^\top\sum\limits_{\bm y_i\neq\bm y_j}\exp\left((\bm y_j-\bm y_i)^\top \bm B\bm W^\top\bm x_i\right)(\bm y_j-\bm y_i)
\\
=\frac{J_i^2}{n(c-1)}\bm B^\top\sum\limits_{\forall j}\exp\left((\bm y_j-\bm y_i)^\top \bm B\bm W^\top\bm x_i\right)(\bm y_j-\bm y_i)
$$

Let $m_j=J_i^2\exp\left((\bm y_j-\bm y_i)^\top \bm B\bm W^\top\bm x_i\right)$, then
$$\nabla_{\bm W^\top\bm x_i}J=\frac1{n(c-1)}\bm B^\top\sum\limits_{\forall j}m_j(\bm y_j-\bm y_i)
\\
=\frac1{n(c-1)}\bm B^\top\left[\sum\limits_{\forall j}m_j\bm y_j-\bm y_i\sum\limits_{\forall j}m_j\right]
$$

Since $\bm y_j$ is one-hot, The term in brackets can be rewritten in vector form.
$$\nabla_{\bm W^\top\bm x_i}J=\frac1{n(c-1)}\bm B^\top\left[\bm m_i-\left(\bm m_i^\top\bm e\right)\bm y_i\right]$$

where $\bm m_i=\begin{bmatrix} m_1 & m_2 & \dots & m_c\end{bmatrix}^\top$. From here, one can work upwards, to find $\nabla_{\bm W}J$ as provided previously. Notably, $\bf m_i$ also turns out to be the $i$th row of $\bm M$ mentioned previously.  Hopefully, I did not miss something.

Comment: What does this have to do with gradient descent?

Comment: I am using GD to minimize the cost function. In the case described above, it would be a full batch GD until convergence, that is $\nabla_{\bf W}J=\mathbf 0$. I know that the global minimum corresponds to $J\to-1$ as mentioned but I am interested in conditions under which it converges to a local minimum if indeed it does.

Comment: What is a "one-hot vector"?

Comment: "one-hot" vector is a binary vector containing all zeros except one non-zero element which equals one. Thus, there is only one "hot" dimension with a value of one, rest are zeros. E.g., $[0,0,1,0]$ is one-hot but $[0,1,0,1]$ is not. I apologize for the confusion. It is a popular term for such vectors in data science field.

Comment: Thus, the ${\bf y}_i$ are the columns of the identity matrix, right?

Comment: Indeed they are. Although, in my question, $\bf Y$ can have repeated columns since it is a $c\times n$ matrix.

Comment: Let me see if I understand your cost function given the possibility of repeated columns in $Y$.  If $j\ne i$ but $y_j=y_i$ then $y_j$ still contributes $e^0=\tt1$ to the sum $\sum_{j\ne i}\quad$ right?  Or did you mean to exclude those terms from the sum as well?

Comment: As a correction, I should say $\bf y_i \neq \bf y_j$ instead of $j\neq i$, since $\bf y_i $ and $\bf y_j$ can be equal even for distinct $i$ and $j$. $i$ indexes into $\bf X$ and $j$ indexes into $\bf I\in \mathbb R^{c\times c}$. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @Phoenix Thanks for clearing that up, but it leads me to a second question.  The factor of $\frac{\tt1}{c-\tt1}$ preceding the sum would produce the **average** of the terms being summed $\sf IFF$ the restriction were still $j\ne i$, but in light of the new constraint it needs to be modified if the intent is to average the remaining terms.

Comment: Regarding the factor of $\frac1{c-1}$, it should be fine because there will always exist one and only one $j$, out of $c$ such vectors for which $\bf y_j=\bf y_i$ (since $\bf y_j\in\bf I^c$), leaving the other $c-1$ terms intact. Regarding your second question, $\bf y_i$ corresponds to a column vector in $\bf Y$ which has as many vectors as in $\bf X$. Since $c<n$, it follows that $\bf Y$ will have repeated vectors from $\bf I$. This means that for distinct $\bf x_i, \bf x_k\in\bf X$, $\bf y_i, \bf y_k\in\bf Y$ can be the same because we selected them from $\bf I$. Hope I was able to explain.

Comment: I get a slightly different result for the gradient
$$X\Big[M-\operatorname{Diag}(Me)\Big]Y^TB$$ Interestingly, the term in brackets is the  _Laplacian_ of the $M$ matrix.

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\R#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\h{\odot}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\e{{\varepsilon}}
\def\bR#1{\big[#1\big]}
\def\BR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\op{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\tfracLR#1#2{\LR{\tfrac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\HH{H^{-2}}
\def\H{H^{-1}}
$This is too big for a comment, but here is how I calculated the gradient. In addition to the Hadamard product $(\h)$ I'll use the Frobenius product $(:)$
$$\eqalign{
&A:B = \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n \LR{A\h B}_{ij}
   \;=\; \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \\
&B:B = \frob{B}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
&A:B = B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
&\LR{XY}:B = X:\LR{BY^T} \;=\; Y:\LR{X^TB} \\
&C:\LR{A\h B} = \LR{C\h A}:B \\
}$$
Let $\{\e_k\in\R n\}$ denote the standard basis vectors and note that
$$\eqalign{
x_k = X\e_k,\qquad y_k = Y\e_k \\
}$$
The following variables are useful
$$\eqalign{
I &= \sum_k \e_k\e_k^T \qquad{\;\;\rm and}\quad\;\; e = \sum_k \e_k \\
P &= X^TWB^TY
  \qiq p = \diag P \;=\; \sum_k \e_k\LR{\e_k^TP\e_k} \\
G &= \sum_j\sum_k \e_k \BR{\e_k^TP\LR{\e_j-\e_k}} \e_j^T
  \;\equiv\; \LR{P - pe^T} \\
A &= \exp(G) \qiq dA = A\odot dG \\
H &= (c-2)I + \Diag{Ae} \;=\; H^T  \\
M &= \tfracLR{c-1}{n}\BR{\diag\HH\:e^T}\h A  \\
}$$
where the `exp()` function is applied elementwise.

Rewrite the cost function using the above notation,
and calculate its gradient
$$\eqalign{
J &= \tfracLR{1-c}{n}I:\H \\
\\
dJ &= \tfracLR{c-1}{n}I:\H\,dH\,\H \\
 &= \tfracLR{c-1}{n}\HH:dH \\
 &= \tfracLR{c-1}{n}\HH:\Diag{dA\;e} \\
 &= \tfracLR{c-1}{n}\diag\HH\:e^T:\c{dA} \\
 &= \tfracLR{c-1}{n}\diag\HH\:e^T:\CLR{A\odot dG} \\
 &\equiv M:dG \\
 &= M:\LR{dP-\c{dp}\,e^T} \\
 &= M:dP - Me:\c{\diag{dP}} \\
 &= \BR{M-\Diag{Me}}:dP \\
 &= \BR{M-\Diag{Me}}:\LR{X^T\,dW\:B^TY} \\
 &= X\BR{M-\Diag{Me}}Y^TB:dW \\
\\
\grad{J}{W}
 &= X\BR{M-\Diag{Me}}Y^TB \\
}$$

Comment: Thanks for your effort! However, I see a problem here. $e$ is in the null space of $\Big[M-\operatorname{Diag}(Me)\Big]$ which implies that the gradient would be zero if all rows of $Y^T$ are the same, however, this seems not to be the case when you look at the objective. Also, my question isn't addressed in your answer.

Comment: Note that in my question it is not necessary, but still a possibility that all "one-hot" vectors $y_i\in Y$ are the same, but $y_j$ will never be, because, $y_j\in I$. The only similarity between $y_i$ and $y_j$ is their structure, i.e., both are binary vectors with only one of their dimensions set to $1$. The summation term in the denominator goes from $j=1$ to $j=c$ such that $y_i\neq y_j$, so $y_j\in I$ is always distinct for each summation term in the denominator. We always have $c-1$ non-zero terms in the denominator to sum up, even if all $y_i\in Y$ are the same.

Comment: is it ok to rewrite the cost function as $
\phi
=
\sum_n
\frac
{\mathbf{y}_n^T 
\exp \left( \mathbf{z}_n \right)}
{\mathbf{w}_n^T 
\exp \left( \mathbf{z}_n \right)}
$ where $\mathbf{z}_n
=\mathbf{B} \mathbf{W}^T \mathbf{x}_n$
ans $\mathbf{w}_n$ is a weight vector ?